# Django intermediate M2M a[href] not saving data to database

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

Working on a project with Django (social platform) where user can create group for other users to join or leave.

This is my first Django project, i'm not sure if my implementation of the join and leave group logic is right. i have a join button which is an a[href] tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'join' group.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Join Group</a>
```

Clicking it supposed to add the user to the group. Below are the models and views:

**models.py:**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')
    counter = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def group(request, pk):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'group/group.html', {'group': group})


@login_required
def join(request, pk):
    _group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
    membership = Membership()
    membership.group = _group
    membership.person = request.user
    membership.save()
    return group(request, pk)
```

The user doesn't get saved to the membership table. What is the best way to approach this? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Also tried this view function for the join button:

```
@login_required
def join(request, pk):
    _group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
    membership = Membership.objects.create(user=request.user, group=_group)
    membership.save()
    return group(request, pk)
```

**urls:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.groups, name='groups'),
    url(r'^all/$', views.all, name='all'),
    url(r'^create_group/$', views.CreateGroup.as_view(), name='create_group'),
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', views.group, name='group'),
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', views.join, name='join'),
]
```

Comment: You should show your URLs. The request is clearly not being routed to that view, as you would get an error because you are not returning an httpresponse. In any case, you really shouldn't make db changes in a get request.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks the quick response. i've added my urls now. should i use a form instead?

Comment: You have two URLs that are exactly the same, Django will always use the first one only. And yes, you should use a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Using a form now

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'join' %}" onsubmit="return true">
        {%csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="{{ group.id }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Join Group">
```

join url is:

```
url(r'^join/$', views.join, name='join')
```